# Web API custom authentication filter

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am trying to make a custom filter for my web api controllers part of a ASP.NET MVC 5 website/application to check the requests headers for a specific token which i have stored in the database. Most examples I found were containing user credentials and then the user was authenticated using identity. Not exactly what I am looking for.

This is the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005485/RESTful-Day-sharp-Security-in-Web-APIs-Basic) I found and am currently following.

The web API should only handle "external" HTTP calls, the website side will have its own controllers presently (but may be subject to change).

This filter should interface with identity 2 system already present if possible.

What I do is that I send user credentials then, assign a token to the user and then I want to use that token to authenticate the request. Is there a way I can just filter the request based on the token or do I need to use Owin identity and their token management. I am using a mobile client (currently iOS, will include android too) to make the calls. Any example or tutorial I could refer to ?

The token is currently a random combination of alphanumeric characters and symbols.

Thank you.

P.S. I can post code snippets and stuff where needed.

Edit: The HTTPRequests will be filtered based on whether they contain a token present within our database/system. Requests that do contain a token or are not present within our system will receive unauthorised error (401?)

Comment: So the token is in the HTTP Request header?

Comment: Yes, the token is in the request header.

Comment: What do you mean filter the request based on the token? Will not every HTTPReqeust contain the token, or is there a need to only filter requests when they have a token?

Comment: The HTTPRequests will be filtered based on whether they contain a token present within our database/system. Requests that do contain a token or are not present within our system will receive unauthorised error (401?)

Comment: So add your filter and do the DB request, if the token doesn't exists, then redirect the HTTP request..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you thought that sending user name and password to every request is not good.Refer my below implementation with out user name and password, since we are  don't send user name and password with every request.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// read requested header and validated
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var identity = FetchFromHeader(actionContext);

            if(identity != null)
            {
                var securityService = actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ILoginService)) as ILoginService;
                if (securityService.TokenAuthentication(identity))
                {
                    CurrentThread.SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(identity), null), null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                return;
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// retrive header detail from the request 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string FetchFromHeader(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            string requestToken = null;

            var authRequest = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authRequest != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authRequest.Scheme) && authRequest.Scheme == "Basic")
                requestToken = authRequest.Parameter;

            return requestToken;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am been error at **ILoginService**. How to fix this it? @RajA

Answer (score 3):

You can make this filter unit testable by injecting the service dependencies via property(property injection). For custom attributes, we don't want to pass the dependencies via constructor. We want the attribute easy to 
use. To rewrite what @Raj already started, it can look like this:

```
   public class AuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        [Dependency]
        public ILoginService LoginService { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// read requested header and validated
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var identity = FetchFromHeader(actionContext);

            if (identity != null)
            {
                if (LoginService.TokenAuthentication(identity))
                {
                    CurrentThread.SetPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(identity), null), null, null);

                    //IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(identity), new string[] { "myRole" });
                    //Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    //HttpContext.Current.User = principal;             
                }
                else
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                return;
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// retrive header detail from the request 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string FetchFromHeader(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            string requestToken = null;

            var authRequest = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (authRequest != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authRequest.Scheme) && authRequest.Scheme == "Basic")
                requestToken = authRequest.Parameter;

            return requestToken;
        }
    }
```